# How do I hash strings to RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, file, hash

I'm having trouble understand how my teacher wants us to do the second part of this project. The first part was easy getting the employees and putting it in a r.a.f, but I dont understand how i can hash ssn which is a string. Can someone please explain it. I put the directions just in case.Thanks

ssn: String(9 characters),
fullname : string of 50 characters,
salary: float, and 
age: int

1.The program writes at least 20 Employees and stores them sequentially on the random access, and then sequentially reads and prints all Employees in a readable format.

2.Redo the previous part assuming the employees are stored based on hashing the ssn( non-sequentially)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you would call [`String.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a hash of pretty much any type. If I understand correctly, we want to use a distinct data value, an SSN, to make a hash that is used for keying into some random-access store.

My first thought is, if you need a strong hash based on more than just the String itself, to wrap the SSN in a Class, and use that to both store and fetch the SSN value, as well as provide a hashCode() implementation based on one or more fields along with a seed. This is described a bit in Block's "Effective Java", where a HashCodeUtil class is introduced.

A working example is discussed here: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=28

Comment: to be honest it doesnt seem like I have to do that, from your explanation cant i just hash the string, store it with that hash? but then how do i search it using the normal ssn string.

Comment: All you need to do is pass your string to the hash.put method as the key.   java will turn that string into a hash code.   And when you want to get it out, hash.get that string will again be converted to a code which then looks up your value

Comment: exactly what i was thinking @Totora.

Comment: This will work, but does not quite fulfill the requirements stated in step (2), at least for some interpretations. Also, using a key that has "intelligence" is usually not recommended, especially since you mention random access storage specifically. This is too close to using the SSN as a primary key for my tastes. But, perhaps for this case information hiding is too much; fair enough. (Though, data contracts can change, and once you have gone all-in on using the SSN directly, it's hard not to create a ripple effect if you change this later...)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to implement your own hash table using RandomAccessFile.  If that is true what you need to do is take a hashcode and turn it into a slot number.  To do this modulo divide the hashcode() of the SSN string by some prime number close to double the number of entries you expect in the table. In your case maybe 41. Each slot in the RandomAccessFile is the size of an entry.  In you case 9+50+4+4 = 67.  Multiply the slot number by the entry size to give you the offset of the location in the RandomAccessFile to read and write.

Note that this, as in all hash tables, may lead to collisions. A real world implementation would then handle some kind of entry chaining.

Comment: I dont think he wants us to make a hashtable, seems like I got it to work. Ive emailed him asking tho if he wants a hashtable, but for now ive just hashed the ssn and stored it and to re-get the info i enter the ssn via console and hash it then search the file for that hash.